# Recommended mobile dimensions

Tags: html, mobile, responsive, dimensions

I'm embarking on my first foray into mobile site design - I've set up a method to redirect mobile users to a separate URL, but now I need to design the mobile version of the site (targeting smart phones like Android / iPhone). What dimensions should I create this to? Is there a way to force mobile browsers to scale the content down? (Currently my site just appears very big within the mobile window and you must scroll horizontally and vertically to see it all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

320 X 480 pixels is standard for mobile sites.

Things you ABSOLUTELY MUST KNOW about footers for mobile.
iPhone has the bastard of all browsers and no emulator emultates it correctly for - specifically:
CSS footer style - position:fixed; bottom:0;
Don't even try it.
iPhone only recognizes position:relative;

iPhones do not recoginized the position style of fixed - in case you want a footer to stay on teh bottom.